# How to pass numpy logic functions to Cython correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cython

What declarations should I be incorporating with a logic function / index operation so that Cython does the heavy lifting?

I have two large rasters in the form of numpy arrays of equal size. The first array contains vegetation index values and the second array contains field IDs. The goal is to average vegetation index values by field. Both arrays have pesky nodata values (-9999) that I would like to ignore.

Currently the function takes over 60 seconds to execute, which normally I wouldn’t mind so much but I'll be processing potentially hundreds of images. Even a 30 second improvement would be significant. So I’ve been exploring Cython as a way to help speed things up. I’ve been using the [Cython numpy tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing) as a guide.

[Example data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eqh6lqbgdmzeqns/AABl-_CrP-ATpMRbUWpKVPFJa?dl=0)

test_cy.pyx code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function 

cpdef test():
  cdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=2] ndvi_array = np.load("Z:cython_test/data/ndvi.npy")

  cdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=2] field_array = np.load("Z:cython_test/data/field_array.npy")

  cdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=1] unique_field = np.unique(field_array)
  unique_field = unique_field[unique_field != -9999]

  cdef int field_id
  cdef np.ndarray[np.int16_t, ndim=1] f_ndvi_values
  cdef double f_avg

  for field_id in unique_field :
      f_ndvi_values = ndvi_array[np.logical_and(field_array == field_id, ndvi_array != -9999)]
      f_avg = np.mean(f_ndvi_values)
```

Setup.py code:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('test_cy.pyx'),
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

After some researching and running:

```
cython -a test_cy.pyx
```

It seems the index operation `ndvi_array[np.logical_and(field_array == field_id, ndvi_array != -9999)]` is the bottleneck and is still relying on Python. I suspect I’m missing some vital declarations here. Including `ndim` didn’t have any effect.

I’m fairly new to numpy as well so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: As it  says  in the [docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing) "Gotcha: This efficient indexing only affects certain index operations, namely those with exactly ndim number of typed integer indices. So if v for instance isn’t typed, then the lookup f[v, w] isn’t optimized. On the other hand this means that you can continue using Python objects for sophisticated dynamic slicing etc. just as when the array is not typed."

Comment: The easiest improvement would be to cache `ndvi_array != -9999` (since it doesn't change). Other than that you probably have to rewrite that logical indexing and mean calculation as a 2D loop, but that's more work.

Comment: @Paul So if I’m understanding that correctly, I would need to store ```ndvi_array != -9999``` as a variable and type that, as well as ```field_array = field_id```?

Comment: @wessport I guess that would be a way of approaching it. Or you could loop and put an 'if' statement inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks fairly vectorizable to me, so Cython might not be the best approach. (Cython shines when there are unavoidable fine grained loops.) As your dtype is `int16` there is only a limited range of possible labels, so using `np.bincount` should be fairly efficient. Try something like (this is assuming all your valid values are >= 0 if that is not the case you'd have to shift - or (cheaper) view-cast to `uint16` (since we are not doing any arithmetic on the labels that should be safe) - before using `bincount`):

```
mask = (ndvi_array != -9999) & (field_array != -9999)
nd = ndvi_array[mask]
fi = field_array[mask]
counts = np.bincount(fi, minlength=2**15)
sums = np.bincount(fi, nd, minlength=2**15)
valid = counts != 0
avgs = sums[valid] / counts[valid]
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul for the recommendation! ```np.bincount``` is much more efficient comparatively. 
Can you expand on what you meant by unavoidable fine grained loops? This would be a number of operations executed on arrays of different sizes for instance?

Comment: @wessport What I meant is things that have to be done one array element after the other and are not covered by ufuncs. So adding two arrays, no prob. because 'a + b' does the loop over elements in C. Similarly 'cumsum(a)' While this has do be done one element after the other it still runs in C. But if there is something less standard which can't be pieced together from numpy building blocks and the only way you can find is to do a Python loop over the elements of some array, then Cython can gain you ridiculous speedups.